# lxml for Qpython3 (Python3 on Android)

Tags: android, python, lxml, qpython, qpython3

Is there a way to install lxml on Qpython3(Python3 on Android)?

I could not find anything on google. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a pure python library, so you can't install it through qpython3's pip_console.py.

you can send a request in https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython.org/issues, the developer team is very active, they may give a solution.